# Display a load more button in a mapped json array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have a fetch request for my sample application, that receive a json. I've mapped this json and i can potentially display over 100 elements with a single request.

The problem is that i want to implement a load more button to make the page more simple to read and load (for example i want to display 20 items, and other 20 if the load more button is triggered).

Here is my sample request in a reproducible demo: https://jsfiddle.net/0mc3gn9f/

How can i implement a load more button in vanilla js?

```js
let tableBody = document.getElementById("tab-body");


fetch("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=eur&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false", {cache: "no-cache"})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    this.criptoInfo = data;
    return this.criptoInfo;
  })
  .then((coinMap) => {
    let cripto = coinMap.map((coin) => {
        console.log(coin)
      let tr = document.createElement("tr");
      tableBody.appendChild(tr);
      tr.innerHTML = `<td>
        <div class="name-value coin-container">
            <img class="coin-image" src="${coin.image}">
            <p class="coin-name">${coin.name}</p>
            <p class="coin-abbrName">${coin.symbol}</p>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td><p class="price coin-name"><b>${coin.current_price} €</b></p></td>
    <td><p class="value-item coin-name">${coin.ath_change_percentage} %</p></td>
    <td><p class="value-item coin-name">${coin.high_24h} €</p></td>
    <td><p class="value-item coin-name">${coin.market_cap} €</p></td>
    <td><p class="value-item coin-name">${coin.total_supply} €</p></td>
    `;
    });
  });
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@0,100;0,400;0,700;0,900;1,100&display=swap");
nav {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #040418;
  height: 20vh;
}
nav .logo {
  width: 110px;
}
nav .logo img {
  width: 100%;
}
nav a {
  margin: 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  color: #e0dada;
}

.box-table {
  margin-inline: 4rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 1rem;
  text-align: justify;
}
.box-table .coin-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.box-table .coin-container img {
  width: 40px;
}
.box-table .coin-container .coin-abbrName {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: dimgray;
}
.box-table .name-value {
  width: 300px;
}
.box-table .price {
  width: 200px;
}
.box-table .value-item {
  width: 180px;
}
.box-table .more-coins {
  width: 250px;
  padding: 1rem;
  justify-content: center;
}

thead:after {
  content: "@";
  display: block;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-indent: -99999px;
}

#tab-body > tr {
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04) 0px 3px 5px;
}

.presentation {
  height: 80vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #3903f9;
  background: linear-gradient(352deg, #3903f9 45%, #040418 70%);
}
.presentation .titles {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.presentation .titles h1 {
  color: rgba(40, 40, 236, 0.966);
  font-size: 3rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2rem;
  margin-top: 4rem;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}
.presentation .titles h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  width: 500px;
  line-height: 3rem;
  justify-self: center;
  color: #fff;
}
.presentation .image-home-container {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.presentation .image-home-container .image-home {
  width: 250px;
  align-self: center;
  border: 0;
}
.presentation .image-home-container .image-home img {
  width: 100%;
}
.presentation button {
  width: 250px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #080808;
  border: 2px solid white;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  color: #fff;
}
.presentation button:hover {
  width: 300px;
  transition: 2s;
  font-size: 2rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: black;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Lato", serif;
}

body,
html {
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
}

.header-container {
  background-image: url(./assets/header.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  position: relative;
}
.header-container .heading-title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.48rem;
  font-family: Lato, serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  background: #0000005c;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.header-container .heading-title h3 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 300;
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
  <link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inconsolata:wght@400;700&family=Roboto+Mono:wght@300&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet"
  />
</head>
<body>
<!-- TABLE -->
<section>
  <div class="box-table">
    <table id="tab">
      <thead id="table-head">
      <tr>
        <th class="name-value">Nome</th>
        <th class="price">Prezzo</th>
        <th class="value-item">Variazione</th>
        <th class="value-item">Volume(24 h)</th>
        <th class="value-item">Capitalizzazione mercato</th>
        <th class="value-item">Offerta</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="tab-body"></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <button id="load-more">Load More</button>
</section>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=eur&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false
```

Actually, your API call already have

`per_page=100` which is to get 100 items per page

`page=1` which is to get data by page number

So we just need to change `per_page=20` and make API call with incremental `page` number correctly

```js
//global variable for pageIndex and it starts from 1
let pageIndex = 1

let tableBody = document.getElementById("tab-body");

//populate a click event to load more button
const loadMoreButton = document.getElementById("load-more");
loadMoreButton.addEventListener("click", () => { fetchData(pageIndex++) }); //every click pageIndex increases 1

//fetch data with page index value
function fetchData(pageIndexValue = 1) {
fetch(`https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=eur&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=20&page=${pageIndexValue}&sparkline=false`, {cache: "no-cache"})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    this.criptoInfo = data;
    return this.criptoInfo;
  })
  .then((coinMap) => {
    let cripto = coinMap.map((coin) => {
      let tr = document.createElement("tr");
      tableBody.appendChild(tr);
      tr.innerHTML = `<td>
        <div class="name-value coin-container">
            <img class="coin-image" src="${coin.image}">
            <p class="coin-name">${coin.name}</p>
            <p class="coin-abbrName">${coin.symbol}</p>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td><p class="price coin-name"><b>${coin.current_price} €</b></p></td>
    <td><p class="value-item coin-name">${coin.ath_change_percentage} %</p></td>
    <td><p class="value-item coin-name">${coin.high_24h} €</p></td>
    <td><p class="value-item coin-name">${coin.market_cap} €</p></td>
    <td><p class="value-item coin-name">${coin.total_supply} €</p></td>
    `;
    });
  });
}

//initial call when page load
fetchData(pageIndex++)
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@0,100;0,400;0,700;0,900;1,100&display=swap");
nav {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #040418;
  height: 20vh;
}
nav .logo {
  width: 110px;
}
nav .logo img {
  width: 100%;
}
nav a {
  margin: 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  color: #e0dada;
}

.box-table {
  margin-inline: 4rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 1rem;
  text-align: justify;
}
.box-table .coin-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.box-table .coin-container img {
  width: 40px;
}
.box-table .coin-container .coin-abbrName {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: dimgray;
}
.box-table .name-value {
  width: 300px;
}
.box-table .price {
  width: 200px;
}
.box-table .value-item {
  width: 180px;
}
.box-table .more-coins {
  width: 250px;
  padding: 1rem;
  justify-content: center;
}

thead:after {
  content: "@";
  display: block;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-indent: -99999px;
}

#tab-body > tr {
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04) 0px 3px 5px;
}

.presentation {
  height: 80vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #3903f9;
  background: linear-gradient(352deg, #3903f9 45%, #040418 70%);
}
.presentation .titles {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.presentation .titles h1 {
  color: rgba(40, 40, 236, 0.966);
  font-size: 3rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2rem;
  margin-top: 4rem;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}
.presentation .titles h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  width: 500px;
  line-height: 3rem;
  justify-self: center;
  color: #fff;
}
.presentation .image-home-container {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.presentation .image-home-container .image-home {
  width: 250px;
  align-self: center;
  border: 0;
}
.presentation .image-home-container .image-home img {
  width: 100%;
}
.presentation button {
  width: 250px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #080808;
  border: 2px solid white;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  color: #fff;
}
.presentation button:hover {
  width: 300px;
  transition: 2s;
  font-size: 2rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: black;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Lato", serif;
}

body,
html {
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
}

.header-container {
  background-image: url(./assets/header.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  position: relative;
}
.header-container .heading-title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.48rem;
  font-family: Lato, serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  background: #0000005c;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.header-container .heading-title h3 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 300;
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
  <link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inconsolata:wght@400;700&family=Roboto+Mono:wght@300&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet"
  />
</head>
<body>
<!-- TABLE -->
<section>
  <div class="box-table">
    <table id="tab">
      <thead id="table-head">
      <tr>
        <th class="name-value">Nome</th>
        <th class="price">Prezzo</th>
        <th class="value-item">Variazione</th>
        <th class="value-item">Volume(24 h)</th>
        <th class="value-item">Capitalizzazione mercato</th>
        <th class="value-item">Offerta</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="tab-body"></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <button id="load-more">Load More</button>
</section>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The full implementation here https://jsfiddle.net/691jp7cy/

Answer (score 1):

Here is an updated fiddle.  I just stored the data, and show 20 results each time the button is clicked.

https://jsfiddle.net/k2zums9n/

```
let cripto = [];

let loadSize = 20;
let rowCount = 0;

let formatRow = coin => {
    let tr = document.createElement("tr");
  tr.innerHTML = `<td>
        <div class="name-value coin-container">
            <img class="coin-image" src="${coin.image}">
            <p class="coin-name">${coin.name}</p>
            <p class="coin-abbrName">${coin.symbol}</p>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td><p class="price coin-name"><b>${coin.current_price} €</b></p></td>
    <td><p class="value-item coin-name">${coin.ath_change_percentage} %</p></td>
    <td><p class="value-item coin-name">${coin.high_24h} €</p></td>
    <td><p class="value-item coin-name">${coin.market_cap} €</p></td>
    <td><p class="value-item coin-name">${coin.total_supply} €</p></td>
    `;
  return tr;
}

let showMore = () => {
    let tableBody = document.getElementById("tab-body");
  let loaded = 0;
    cripto.forEach((coin)=>{
    if(!coin.show && loaded < loadSize){
        coin.show = true;
      loaded += 1;
      tableBody.appendChild(formatRow(coin));
    }
  })
}

fetch("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=eur&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false", {cache: "no-cache"})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    this.criptoInfo = data;
    return this.criptoInfo;
  })
  .then((coinMap) => {
    cripto = coinMap;
    showMore();
  });
 
document.getElementById("load-more").addEventListener("click", function() {
  showMore();
});
```